# css div overflow and dynamic horizontal size

Tags: css, dynamic-css

I have a web page that shows lots of tabular data and each of these tables needs to be placed on one horizontal line. I have mocked up an example below:

```
<html>
<style>
  .outer{width:300px;height:300px;overflow: scroll;}
  .inner{white-space: nowrap;}
  .inline{float: left;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="inline"><table><tr><td>stuff</td></tr></table></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having problems that the inner div wraps the table divs unless I set it to have a large width such as 4000px. Is there a nice way of keeping all of the tables inline even if they exceed the size of the outer div with just css?

Comment: You're going to have to give more examples here. What is the inner div you're talking about? What are "the items"?

Comment: I have tried to make this more clear.

Comment: Is it just when "stuff" is exceptionally long, or always wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.inline{float: left;}` to `.inline{display:inline-block;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/QLe5r/

Answer (score 2):

Us this property:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: yeah i tried this but they still wrap. Not sure if I made all of the divs that contain tables to be inline though so will have a quick go at this and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the float: left on divs "inline". Instead uses display: inline-block, (and display: inline for IE, I think. Check).

Comment: works in firefox but not in ie and this was for ie6 - was nearly two years ago though so not too worried about it anymore ;)

Answer (score -2):

Why on EARTH do you have tons of tables inside tons of divs?!? That defeats the purpose of using tables for tabular data...when you are doing tabular data you should just use tables...not apply useless combinations.

Simply use one table and use `<td>stuff</td>` each time you have more data to add...td's are horizontal based anyway so you wouldn't even have to bother with css to have it extend.

Comment: I was creating server racks and displaying a whole row of servers. I guess these should all be div data but I had built the original (showing one at a time) using tables for ease.